# Unknown element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? In Vue-Router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuex

I have an issue I looked everywhere but not found suitable solution.

[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

--->  at src/App.vue

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Generic from './Generic.vue' import ABC from './abc.vue' import  ueRouter from 'vue-router' import { routes } from './router.js'
Vue.component('vue-header', Header); Vue.component('vue-generic', eneric); Vue.component('vue-abc', ABC);
Vue.use('VueRouter');

const router = new VueRouter({
routes,
  mode: 'history'
});
new Vue({  el: '#app',  routes,  render: h => h(App) })
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know that this causes that specific error, but your code will fail because when you instantiate a Vue you need to instantiate it with the `router` not the `routes`. It should be `new Vue({  el: '#app',  router,  render: h => h(App) })`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call `Vue.use()` on a string. So, instead of having `Vue.use('VueRouter')` as in:

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use('VueRouter'); // don't call .use() on a string
```

Call `Vue.use()` on the previously imported reference (e.g. `Vue.use(VueRouter)`) as in:

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter); // call .use() on the imported reference
```

Comment: I recommend placing the comments outside the code block, this allows people with screen readers to have the code to be read for them if they are helping a college/friend

Comment: @Ferrybig thanks for the tip. I never thought of that (ahem.. typical!), but I tried to make it better.

Comment: Let me checl this

Comment: Great! Consider accepting the answer to let us know it's been solved https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/219205